# Sed: How to delete a "{" that the first character of the current line and add a "{" to the end of the previous line via sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I  am writing  a sed  script , but i don't know how to implement the follow functions:

**Update:**

If the first non-white-space character of the current line is "{",   delete it and add a "{"  to the end of the previous line.

For example:

```
class test
{
     function fun()
     {
         if(true)
         {
             //do something
         }
     }
}
```

I need the follow result:

```
class test{

     function fun(){

         if(true){

             //do something
         }
     }
}
```

Who can help me?

Comment: How about finding a proper code reformatting utility that supports your programming language, and has decent style options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way

```
sed 'N;:1;$!N;s/\n{/{\n/;P;D;b1' file
```

Input

```
123
456
{345
678
{10112
{232
```

Output

```
123
456{
345
678 {
10112{
232
```

If there are "spaces" before the `{`

```
sed 'N;:1;$!N;s/\n[[:space:]]*{/{\n/;P;D;b1' file
```

Will also strip empty lines before the `{`

Comment: Thank you ,@123 , I made some supplements for  problem  ,and it  is updated.

Comment: @sis Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\s*\n\s*{/{\n/;P;D' file
```